# Multi-Paragraph Speech with Automatic Speech Marks

Tags: csquotes

I would like to know if I can have a paragraph break in speech and have the speech marks appear automatically. This would help with converting long text from British style to American style for instance. I would like the text to appear like this, keeping the LaTeX as simple as possible:

> 'This is a quote,' he said. 'But what is possible?
>
> 'Can I do this?'

Here is a MWE of what I can currently obtain but without speech marks at the start of the second paragraph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
    \enquote{This is a quote} he said. \enquote{But what is possible?

    Can I do this}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust the quote style for the language in use with `csquote`'s `\DeclareQuoteStyle` (with middle marks added to the original in `csquotes.def`):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\DeclareQuoteStyle[british]{english}
  {\textquoteleft}
  [\textquoteleft]% middle outer mark
  {\textquoteright}
  [0.05em]
  {\textquotedblleft}
  [\textquotedblleft]% middle inner mark
  {\textquotedblright}

\begin{document}
\enquote{This is a quote} he said. \enquote{But what is possible?

  Can I do this}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A simple idea is to add a left quote by default to each paragraph using `` \everypar{`} ``.

Of course this is only desired within the `\enquote` command, so you can redefine `\enquote` to include `\everypar`. The non-starred version of `\enquote` is defined in `csquotes.sty` with a single line of code, so it is easy to copy that definition in your own document and change it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\makeatletter
\long\def\csq@quote@i#1#2#3{%
  \csq@bqgroup#1\everypar{`}\csq@oqopen@i#3\csq@qclose@i{#2}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \enquote{This is a quote} he said. \enquote{But what is possible?

    Can I do this}.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that `\everypar` is used for many things in LaTeX so it can be overwritten if the contents of `\enquote` contains more complex code, resulting in the quote not being applied. However, for regular text it should be relatively safe.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! I changed the `\everypar` argument to `\csq@qopen` so that it switches with style. Otherwise works well, thanks. Will now do some reading around `\everypar` to understand how/when it might fail.

Comment: This may work fine but I would recommend using the [answer by gusbrs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/626095/) instead (and also change the accept mark to that answer). I didn't know that `csquotes` actually has a setting for 'middle mark' but that is arguably more robust than setting `\everypar` yourself.